# highlighted shadow color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

How to set the shadowColor of a highlighted Text?

```
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:90.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
titleLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0);
```

I'm looking for something like: `titleLabel.highlightedTextColor.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 if(!yourlabel.highlighed)
 {
     [yourLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
 }
 else
 {
     [yourLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
 }
```

EDIT:
A UIlabel has a property called highlighted and is a BOOL. You can check if it's true or not and change the shadow color at the moment you want it done.

Comment: No, he wanted to have 2 different shadows one for standard state and one for highlighted

Comment: I think who want to do that statically =)

Comment: Well you can only statically allocate a highlightedtextcolor at default uilabels/uibuttons. 
If you want to set it by state you need to make a customlabel/custombutton and do it there.

Comment: Thanks, but in what event should I check if the label is highlighed? I have the label inside a cell of a tablerow.

Comment: Question: do you want to change that textshadow upon selection of the tablecell? if so it is really simple.

Comment: Yeh, @Jimmy. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to have 2 shadows, one for the normal text and other for the highlighted text. Now I'm trying this, and it seems that work. Thanks for the help Totumus & Nekto:

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1000];
    
    
    if(!titleLabel.highlighted)
    {
        [titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    }

Comment: You might also want to create a subclass of UILabel, overwrite setHighlighted and put the color logic in there. Just make sure to call [super setHighlighted:].

Answer (score 2):

I was annoyed by this oversight from Apple, too, and created a subclass of `UILabel` that adds the missing `highlightedShadowColor` and `highlightedShadowOffset` properties.

By default it just disables the shadow in highlighted mode and sets the offset to the reverse of the standard offset.

```
@interface FTLabel : UILabel
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *highlightedShadowColor;
@property(nonatomic) CGSize highlightedShadowOffset;
@end


@interface FTLabel ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *savedShadowColor;
@property(nonatomic) CGSize savedShadowOffset;
@end

@implementation FTLabel

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)configure {
    self.highlightedShadowColor = nil;
    self.highlightedShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(self.shadowOffset.width * (-1), self.shadowOffset.height * (-1));

    self.savedShadowColor = self.shadowColor;
    self.savedShadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    self.shadowColor = self.highlighted ? self.highlightedShadowColor : self.savedShadowColor;
    self.shadowOffset = self.highlighted ? self.highlightedShadowOffset : self.savedShadowOffset;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What I did in the end is to create a second `UILabel` underneath the primary `UILabel` to act as a shadow.

Don't set shadows on your primary and shadow labels. For the shadow label, set the 'Normal Color' to what you wanted your shadow color to be and set the highlighted color to 'Clear Color'.

Obviously you have to update the shadow label each time you update the primary label. Not a big price to pay in many cases.

Hope that helps!